# Second Level Cache (Ehcache) in Hibernate along with Hibernate Search

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, ehcache, hibernate-search

I am using Spring Data JPA with hibernate as the underlying implementation.
For my full text search and few other search queries i am using Hibernate Search.

I was thinking of enabling second level cache using Ehcache for queries which are on fields which are not Indexed.

Is it possible to use both these together and would this strategy be of any value.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using non Hibernate Search (Lucene) queries as well? If not, there is no use for query caching. If you use non Lucene queries though, it might make sense. However, I would recommend to drive all queries via Hibernate Search and just ensure that all data needed for the searches is indexed. If this does not answer your question, you could maybe provide a more concrete example.

Comment: Ya as of now I am using a mix of both lucene and non lucene queries,hence was looking at second level cache

Comment: if you are using a mix of query types, you can speed up the ORM specific queries via the query cache. Second level entity caching should benefit both cases by the way. Are you making use of this as well? But as said, I probably would drive all queries via Hibernate Search.

Comment: You mean second level cache will improve my Hibernate search performance as well ?

Comment: It depends. The default behavior of Hibernate Search (unless you use projections) is to do a search against the Lucene index to determine the primary keys of the entities matching your query. Then the matching entities are loaded from the database (so that you deal with managed entities). If you have second level entity caching enabled you might indeed benefit here in case the entities in question are cached.